# tabs when using 'screen'

Tags: gnu-screen

I am using **Ubuntu** 10.04. After I installed `screen`:

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```

I made two **ssh** connections to two remote servers by doing the following things step by step (I do the following steps according to the [document here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen)):

**1.** open a termnal window, run command `screen`

**2.** press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to create a new virtual console

**3.** `ssh usr@IP1`

**At this point,** I have one virtual console which shows I have connected to the remote server(IP1).

**4.** press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to create a new virtual console

**5.** `ssh usr@IP2`

So, now I have connected to two remote servers(IP1 & IP2). **But**, **I do not have two tabs** on one terminal window, instead, I have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> to switch between the two virtual console in **one** terminal window.

Isn't it so that by using `screen`, I could have **two tabs** in one terminal window, with each tab display one connection to one remote server. Why I do not have the **tabs** in my terminal window?

Answer (score 31):

Here's my [`.screenrc`](https://gist.github.com/1442708) that i use everywhere to see my `screen` numbers as *tabs* at the bottom of the window and an informational line above the *tabs*. The part you really need is under "look and feel".

```
# skip the startup message
startup_message off

# go to home dir
chdir

# Automatically detach on hangup. 
autodetach on

# Change default scrollback value for new windows
defscrollback 10000

# start with visual bell as default
vbell on
vbell_msg "bell on %t (%n)"

# look and feel
caption always "%{= bb}%{+b w}%n %t %h %=%l %H %c"
hardstatus alwayslastline "%-Lw%{= BW}%50>%n%f* %t%{-}%+Lw%<"

activity "Activity in %t(%n)"

shelltitle "shell"
shell -$SHELL
```

You could additionally add the following to automatically add two *tabs* when the `screen` is initially created:

```
screen ssh usr@IP1
screen ssh usr@IP2
```

Also, the status content can be updated using [escape codes](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Hardstatus) issued from shell commands and prompts. For example, i update the status with the current directory using by using this in my `.bashrc`:

```
if [ 'screen' == "${TERM}" ]; then
  export PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\e]2;%s %s\a" "${USER}" "${PWD}" '
fi
```

Comment: I've always wondered why it invariably takes some hardcore configuring in order to make screen not suck to work with.
P.S. Try `shelltitle "$ |shell:"` for appending the command name to the title.

Answer (score 10):

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>"</kbd> you can see the screen "tabs", they aren't supposed to be tabs on your terminal GUI, you can do that manually by creating a new tab at the terminal GUI you are using and then run at the new tab `screen -r` to return to your screen session and then navigate to your desired session with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and a number or <kbd>"</kbd> to see a menu with all your tabs.

You can give a name to each one of you screen "tabs" by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>  then <kbd>A</kbd> .

Comment: Should need to run `screen -r -x` if that screen is already attached in the first tab.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are confusing the tabs on graphic terminals like konsole with those in screen. In screen you switch only the content of a window with the mentioned ^A-Kombinations.
This works also on a non graphic environment.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is quite old, but since Google led me here, others may read this too. So here's my $0.02 hack to mimic tabs within a "screen" session :

Build a status line with :

- on the left side : date/time
- on the right side : local host name + average load
- in the middle : the names of the screen "windows"

  - current window : red text on black background
  - other windows : white text on status line background color (blue, here)

Put in `~/.screenrc` :

```
hardstatus alwayslastline "%{kb}%{c}[%{w}%D %d/%m/%Y %c:%s%{c}] %{w}%-w%{rk}%n %t%{wb}%+w %=%{c}[%{W}%H %l%{c}]"
```

(Maybe this is worth more than $0.02 because I struggled quite a time on this ;-)

To switch from the current window to the previous / next with <kbd>F6</kbd> / <kbd>F7</kbd> keys :

```
bindkey -k k6 prev
bindkey -k k7 next
```

Answer (score 2):

You could configure `screen` to show a status line that can inform you of many things, I suppose also on which screen window you are, but I don't use a status line, so cannot say for sure.

For what I know, `screen` do not create tabs, but you have to switch between screens with the command you indicated, or as I prefer <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd>, etc.

To have more that one tab you can use `gnome-terminal` features, also without screen: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> will create a new tab, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd>, etc. will switch between tabs.

Also I ask why don't you run screen on the server, so using only one ssh connection (but in this case without any tab).