# How to efficiently use Console2 with screen/tmux/byobu?

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, windows, xterm

I'm using [Console 2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) and [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/)'s bash to SSH into my Linux machines. There, I'm [using screen (but considering tmux and/or byobu)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48993/863), but currently simply with one single-terminal session per Console2-tab. However, `screen` won't pass through the xterm escape sequence to change the tab title e.g. to the current path, which would be rather helpfull. So

- How to modify the xterm title from within screen?
- Should I use Console2 tabs or screen windows?
- Anything else to make life easier?

Comment: Slightly related question: [tabs when using 'screen'](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26248/863)

Comment: If you are interesred in, thought, this may be solved in [ConEmu](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/).

Comment: @Maximus What exactly do you mean?

Comment: I think, if you are ready to switch in ConEmu, it is possible to create some AI for tabs detection (afaik, it is possible to show screens/tabs in bottom line of console). Sorry, if I misunderstand the question )

Comment: GNU screen is no longer being actively developed, it's an arm's breadth short of being a dead project. One of the main complaints people have is that it doesn't consistently update tab title. You should use tmux it not only supports that feature but it's likely more secure. I haven't used byobu myself but it's just a wrapper that extends screen or tmux. For a more detailed comparison you should read the question [Byobu versus gnu screen versus tmux](http://superuser.com/questions/423310/byobu-versus-gnu-screen-versus-tmux) on <http://superuser.com>